# Elasticsearch: querying documents by nested Array properties

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery, and-operator

I have something like this as the document:

```
{ name : "name1",
  age : 30,
  address :[{street : "st1" , no : 10}, 
            {street : "st2", no : 20}, 
            {street : "st3", no : 20}]
}
{ name : "name2",
  age : 31,
  address :[{street : "st2" , no : 10}, 
            {street : "st3", no : 20}, 
            {street : "st10", no : 20}]
}
```

I want to issue a query to find the records, in their address array both "st1"
AND "st2" are present. This query should return the first document in the above example.

Find all documents that have address in both "st1" AND "st2". I wrote this query which returns nothing.

```
 {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "address",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "address.street": "st1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "address.street": "st2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I write this query?

Comment: What is not working with your current solution?

Comment: I am using a nested query. When I use for instance "must", It gives me nothing. must [ term : {street : "st1"} , term : {street : "st2"}]. It compares both with each array entries but I want to find "st1" and "st2" inside the array.

Comment: can you put all the details for that in your question?  Thanks!

Comment: @mydogisbox I edited my question a little bit, I hope is that clear by now.

Comment: Can you add some details on where you're getting stuck?  Its difficult to tell what would help you unless you give some details on what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @mydogisbox Could you please if the question is clear, write a query for _search endpoint? As I told when I use a nested query with "must" I get nothing. And now I somehow understand why it happens. But I am looking for a query to fulfill my requirement. But if you think the question is unclear yet, please let me know. The query added to the question.

Comment: yeah i was able to reproduce this issue

Comment: @hyeganeh I know next to nothing about elasticsearch.  I was simply trying to help you add enough details that someone else could help you.

Comment: @mydogisbox Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I could find a way to write a query for mentioned problem with the help of my colleague. It may not the optimal solution but it works.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "address",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "address.street": "st1"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "address",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "address.street": "st2"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you know the more optimal solution, please share it.